# Map in fragment Android result in error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i try to create a map in a fragment in a swipe view, but with this code i have a error in logcat, this is the code:

```
public class Mapa extends Fragment {

    private static final double MARKER_LATITUDE = 42.027325;
    private static final double MARKER_LONGITUDE = -8.640842;
    GoogleMap map;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    public Mapa() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static Mapa newInstance() {
        Mapa fragment = new Mapa();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, container, false);
        final LatLng position = new LatLng(MARKER_LATITUDE, MARKER_LONGITUDE);


        // camera position
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0)
            {
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 17);
                map.animateCamera(cu);
                map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            }
        });
        return android;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        if (f != null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }

}
```

and this is the logcat error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnCameraChangeListener)' on a null object reference
>               at greetrack.estg.ipvc.greentrack.Mapa.onCreateView(Mapa.java:49)

its my first application using maps, maybe somethings is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You havent setup map, its null. So the null reference.

```
Map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapView)).getMap();
```

is one way, or potentially following googles recommendation.  Here is a maps fragment xml.

The xml file i put in isn't showing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key here is the linkk to it.    
    
Add the following code in MainActivity.java.

```
    package com.example.mapdemo;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    }
```

Comment: But my problem is that my application is in FRAGMENTS (swipe view), so i dont have "extend activity" have, "extend fragment", so i have this error went try put your code: Incompatible types, cannot cast 'android.support.v4.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"